# Sparse matrix multiplication complexity and implementation

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have code as below to implement a sparse matrix:

```
close all
n=10;
p = 1/11;
term13 = -(1 / p^2);
term2 = (2 / p^2);
e=ones(n,1);
z=sparse(n,n);
for j=1:n
    vval(j) = barrier(j*p);
    z(j)=term2 + vval(j);
end
h = spdiags([term13*e z(j)*e term13*e], -1:1, n,n);
t=full(h)
```

and `barrier` is a function that has the value of `600` if `0.4<= j*p <=0.6`, otherwise it is zero.
Naturally, I expect the matrix to be as bellow:

```
   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0  -121   842  -121     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0  -121   842  -121     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242
```

but surprisingly it has the form

```
   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0  -121   242  -121     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242  -121
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  -121   242
```

To be exact, I expect  `h(5,5) = h(6,6) = 842` i.e. `242+600`.
but it takes `barrier =0`.

Why is this value incorrect?

Comment: just remove the `j` in `z(j)`when you create your variable `h`.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure:

- why the for loop is needed,
- why you allocate a `nxn` sparse matrix `z`, and then use it with a single index `z(j)`,
- where `vval` is allocated, or used for that matter,
- and why you create a sparse diagonal matrix, only to call `full` in the next line.

But regardless, the issue you asked about is caused by the line

```
h = spdiags([term13*e z(j)*e term13*e], -1:1, n,n);
```

which should be

```
h = spdiags([term13*e, z*e, term13*e], -1:1, n,n);
```

instead (note `z` instead of `z(j)`).